# MYSQL SELECT rows where sum is over 200

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select rows where sum of a row is over 200?

I tried all kinds of combinations with `grouping`, setting AS something and using `WHERE` clause

Current attempt as follow

```
SELECT something.CustomerName, something.CustomerAge, cars.Prices, 
       SUM(cars.Price) AS Amount 
FROM cars 
INNER JOIN something ON something.CustomerNo=Cars.CustomerNo 
GROUP BY AMOUNT 
WHERE AMOUNT > '200'
```

I could not find a tutorial on how to do this

Comment: What you have tried ?? Show us your current attempt.

Comment: I think 200 is a small number, not a big deal

Comment: What is the sum of a row?

Comment: SELECT something.CustomerName, something.CustomerAge, cars.Prices, SUM(cars.Price) AS `Amount` FROM cars INNER JOIN `something` ON  something.CustomerNo=Cars.CustomerNo
GROUP BY `AMOUNT`
WHERE `AMOUNT` > '200'

I have tried not using '' symbols, didn't help

Answer (score 1):

According to your current attempt `where` clause should go before `group by` clause

```
SELECT something.CustomerName, something.CustomerAge, 
       SUM(cars.Price) AS Amount 
FROM cars 
INNER JOIN something ON something.CustomerNo=Cars.CustomerNo  
GROUP BY something.CustomerName, something.CustomerAge
HAVING SUM(cars.Price) > 200;
```

However, you actually need to apply your filter on `Amount` but, you can't do that via `where` clause for that you would need to apply `having` clause filter rather than `where` clause

My today advice is to use table `alise` that could be more readable and easy to *use/implement*

```
SELECT s.CustomerName, s.CustomerAge,
       SUM(c.Price) AS Amount 
FROM cars as c -- use of alise to make it more effective or readable
INNER JOIN something as s ON s.CustomerNo = c.CustomerNo  -- and use that alise everywhere entire the query 
GROUP BY s.CustomerName, s.CustomerAge
HAVING SUM(c.Price) > 200;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to do your maths, then select the values you want

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT (col1 + col2) AS SumOfCols, table.* FROM table
)
WHERE SumOfCols > 200
```

Or another similar approach is to join an ad-hoc table

```
SELECT table.* FROM table
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, (col1 + col2) AS SumOfCols FROM table
) AS TableSums ON TableSums.ID = table. ID
WHERE TableSums.SumOfCols > 200
```